# How to get predicted class using Principal Component Logist Regression model (PCLR model)

Tags: r, logistic-regression, pca

I tried to study the Principal Component Logist Regression model.
I could follow the coding of PCLR model.
However, one question arose in my head.
When I used the logistic regression model (without principal component analysis), I could get the predicted class easily.
But when using PCLR mode, I only got the probability of prediction.

When using the logistic regression model, I could get this result.

```
df<-read.csv("task8.csv")
sample <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), nrow(df), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.7,0.3))
train <- df[sample, ]
test <- df[!sample, ]
model<-glm(Class~.,data=train,family=binomial)
predicted<-predict(model,test)
head(predicted)
```

[results of the prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXJrX.png)

When using the PCLR model, the probability was calculated.
Actually, I used the type=response. I know that is the function to calculate probability.
I tried to type class but it doesn't work. The error pops up and it says link, response, or terms can be allowed. I wonder how I can get the class like using logistic regression (previous one).

```
df<-read.csv("task8.csv")
sample <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), nrow(df), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.7,0.3))
train <- df[sample, ]
test <- df[!sample, ]
pca.out<-prcomp(train[,c(-61)],center=TRUE,scale.=TRUE)
md<-data.frame(Class=train[,"Class"],pca.out$x[,1:20])
PCLR<-glm(Class~.,data=md,family=binomial)
test_pca<-predict(pca.out,nd=test[,1:60])
pred<-predict(PCLR,nd=data.frame(test_pca[,1:20]),type="response")
pred
```

[results of the prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH39u.png)

Comment: Could you just do `pred_class = round(pred)`, which will make those observations with predicted probability bigger than .5 a 1 and 0 otherwise?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I just applied the round function. I am sorry to say that I pretty caught the meaning of the function. If using the round function, the predicted results show as 1 or 0. I think it is the round of the probability and used for calculating the accuracy.  I wonder I could get the classification result (predict) of the test set when using the PCLR method. The training set is transformed to pca. It is difficult for me to get the classification result using PCLR method like the classification result (predict) when using the logistic regression.

Comment: If I understand incorrectly, please let me know.

Comment: You're right, I slightly misunderstood the question.  I posted an answer that should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a `predict` method for `prcomp`, but all `prcomp` does to make the `x` element is multiply the input data (scaled in this case) by the the `rotation` element of the `prcomp` output.  So, to predict using the testing data, you would just multiply the relevant (scaled) elements of the testing data by the `rotation` element of the PCA estimated on the training data.  Here's an example using the `iris` data:

First, we can split into training (odd numbered observations) and testing (even numbered observations) training sets.

```r
library(dplyr)
data(iris)
iris$Class <- as.numeric(iris$Species == "versicolor")
train <- iris[seq(1, nrow(iris), by=2), ]
test <- iris[seq(2, nrow(iris), by=2), ]
```

In both training and testing, you want to standardize the PCA input variables (in this case, the first four columns of the data):

```r
## standardize continuous variables in training
train <- train %>% 
  mutate(across(1:4, ~c(scale(.x))))

## standardize continuous variables in testing 
test <- test %>% 
  mutate(across(1:4, ~c(scale(.x))))
```

Next, do the PCA on the training data and collect the relevant data.

```r
## do PCA on all relevant variables
train.pca <- prcomp(train[,1:4])
md<-data.frame(Class=train$Class,train.pca$x)
```

We can then estimate the model on the training data

```r
## 
PCLR<-glm(Class~.,data=md,family=binomial)
```

Next, use the training PCA `rotation` matrix to calculate the same components for the testing data and generate the predictions.

```r
test.pca.x <- as.matrix(test[,1:4]) %*% train.pca$rotation
pred<-predict(PCLR,nd=as.data.frame(test.pca.x),type="response")
pred
#>          1          3          5          7          9         11         13 
#> 0.11087944 0.20799950 0.08543575 0.11319380 0.40399107 0.07283875 0.39765690 
#>         15         17         19         21         23         25         27 
#> 0.02438208 0.02167528 0.05380879 0.18448684 0.05821109 0.21338980 0.10980254 
#>         29         31         33         35         37         39         41 
#> 0.14271809 0.32132322 0.03088038 0.30053910 0.10252373 0.31544358 0.08076401 
#>         43         45         47         49         51         53         55 
#> 0.20646646 0.05057749 0.06071950 0.07262896 0.30488280 0.35705791 0.48908078 
#>         57         59         61         63         65         67         69 
#> 0.16442812 0.54179637 0.91126367 0.90799754 0.29630021 0.32226332 0.82657416 
#>         71         73         75         77         79         81         83 
#> 0.14854108 0.75173371 0.46528605 0.60178407 0.39051104 0.77817292 0.56468806 
#>         85         87         89         91         93         95         97 
#> 0.32090611 0.31116729 0.34298124 0.73834563 0.65613986 0.57626470 0.43511840 
#>         99        101        103        105        107        109        111 
#> 0.53883788 0.07266489 0.31507437 0.24190271 0.54235329 0.78257363 0.12775847 
#>        113        115        117        119        121        123        125 
#> 0.23390105 0.14338794 0.38820947 0.70947008 0.11420278 0.70304804 0.13627453 
#>        127        129        131        133        135        137        139 
#> 0.35580355 0.37118337 0.62213491 0.31559069 0.85369216 0.04806907 0.23659975 
#>        141        143        145        147        149 
#> 0.10754548 0.43368915 0.05549071 0.55481849 0.05010229
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: you are my life saver!! amazing! I got the results exactly that I need Many Thanks

Comment: Could I ask one more thing? If I want to apply principal components to discriminant function, could I use the similar code that you mentioned by only chainging the glm function to qda function? For example, 
`iris$Class <- as.numeric(iris$Species == "versicolor")
train <- iris[seq(1, nrow(iris), by=2), ]
test <- iris[seq(2, nrow(iris), by=2), ]
train <- train %>% mutate(across(1:4, ~c(scale(.x))))
test <- test %>% mutate(across(1:4, ~c(scale(.x))))
train.pca <- prcomp(train[,1:4])
md<-data.frame(Class=train$Class,train.pca$x)
PCQDA<-qda(Species~.,data=train.pca)`

Comment: `test.pca.x <- as.matrix(test[,1:4]) %*% train.pca$rotation
pred<-predict(PCQDA,nd=as.data.frame(test.pca.x),type="class")
pred`.

As I understand, the basic process is scale, transform to pc, apply regression function, and predict. I think the discriminant function also followe the same process, so I guess the same code can work in both models (in regression model and discriminant anlaysis) by only chaning the regression function to dicriminant fuction.

Comment: However, I unsure if it is the correct approach.

Comment: Sounds ok to me. That’s a question that’s better for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com)